# Generate HTML content of a div with value being filled in with a JS form

Tags: javascript, html

Basically my issue is this, there is a table format I'm using on a website, and it's a pain to manually copy and paste the data for every single table into the HTML.

So I want to try to automate this slightly by only having to copy paste the data into a form, which I then want to generate the HTML so I can just copy and paste that directly on the page.

So I have the form and the table it generates:

```
<h1>Table Generator</h1>School Name:
<form>
    <input id='school_name' type='text' value='School Name'><br>
    City: <input id='city' type='text' value='City'><br>
</form>
<hr>
<h3>2014-15 Data (Top Left Column)</h3>Tuition:
<form>
    <input id='tuition1' type='text' value='Tuition'><br>
    Room & Board: <input id='room1' type='text' value='Room & Board'><br>
    Books: <input id='books1' type='text' value='Books'><br>
    Other Expenses: <input id='other_expenses1' type='text' value='Other Expenses'><br>
    Total: <input id='total1' type='text' value='Total'><br>
</form>
<hr>
<strong>2014-15 Income Brackets Net Cost (Bottom Left Column)</strong><br>
<br>
0-30k:
<form>
    <input id='income_bracket_30k_1' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    30,001-48k: <input id='income_bracket_48k_1' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    48k-75k: <input id='income_bracket_75k_1' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    75k-110k: <input id='income_bracket_110k_1' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    110k+: <input id='income_bracket_110k+_1' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
</form>
<hr>
<h3>2016-17 Data (Top Right Column)</h3>Tuition:
<form>
    <input id='tuition2' type='text' value='Tuition'><br>
    Room & Board: <input id='room2' type='text' value='Room & Board'><br>
    Books: <input id='books2' type='text' value='Books'><br>
    Other Expenses: <input id='other_expenses2' type='text' value='Other Expenses'><br>
    Total: <input id='total2' type='text' value='Total'><br>
</form>
<hr>
<strong>2016-17 Income Brackets Net Cost (Bottom Right Column)</strong><br>
<br>
0-30k:
<form>
    <input id='income_bracket_30k_2' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    30,001-48k: <input id='income_bracket_48k_2' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    48k-75k: <input id='income_bracket_75k_2' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    75k-110k: <input id='income_bracket_110k_2' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    110k+: <input id='income_bracket_110k+_2' type='text' value='$00,000'><br>
    <input onclick='generateTable()' type='button' value='Generate Table'><br>
</form>
<hr>
<br>


<!-- Actual Table -->


<div id="new_table">
    <ul class="xaccordion">
        <li>
            <h4><span id='school_output'></span></h4>
            <div class="xaccordion-content">
                <div class="netprice-table-wrap">
                    <table class="netprice-table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="state-city" colspan="3">City: <span id='city_output'></span></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>2014-15</th>
                                <th>2016-17</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Tuition and Fees</td>
                                <td><span id='tuition1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='tuition2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Room and Board</td>
                                <td><span id='room1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='room2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Books</td>
                                <td><span id='books1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='books2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Other Expenses</td>
                                <td><span id='other_expenses1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='other_expenses2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td><span id='total1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='total2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Net Cost (Actual)<br>
                                2014-15</th>
                                <th>Net Cost (Estimated)<br>
                                2016-17</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$0-$30k</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_30k_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_30k_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$30,001 - $48k</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_48k_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_48k_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$48,001 - $75k</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_75k_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_75k_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$75,001 - $110k</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_110k_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_110k_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$110,001+</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_110k+_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_110k+_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><!--/.netprice-table-->
                </div><!--/.netprice-table-wrap-->
            </div><!--/.xaccordion-content-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/.new_table-->
```

And this would be the JS for the filling in of the values:

```
function generateTable() {
// City and School
var formInput = document.getElementById('school_name').value;
document.getElementById('school_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('city').value;
document.getElementById('city_output').innerHTML = formInput;
// Costs 1
var formInput = document.getElementById('tuition1').value;
document.getElementById('tuition1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('room1').value;
document.getElementById('room1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('books1').value;
document.getElementById('books1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('other_expenses1').value;
document.getElementById('other_expenses1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('total1').value;
document.getElementById('total1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('other_expenses1').value;
document.getElementById('other_expenses1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
// Costs 2
var formInput = document.getElementById('tuition2').value;
document.getElementById('tuition2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('room2').value;
document.getElementById('room2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('books2').value;
document.getElementById('books2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('other_expenses2').value;
document.getElementById('other_expenses2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('total2').value;
document.getElementById('total2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('other_expenses2').value;
document.getElementById('other_expenses2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
// Income Brackets 1
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_30k_1').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_30k_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_48k_1').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_48k_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_75k_1').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_75k_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_1').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k+_1').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k+_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
// Income Brackets 2 
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_30k_2').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_30k_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_48k_2').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_48k_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_75k_2').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_75k_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_2').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k+_2').value;
document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k+_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;}
```

And that all works relatively well, if incredibly sloppy looking. However my question is: I'm at a loss at how to pull the HTML of the table with the newly filled in data? Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/erik-b/pen/wgbqvQ

Comment: What do you mean by "pull the HTML"? Get a copy of it? Most browsers let you right click an element, select "Inspect Element" and then have some form of "Copy HTML" functionality (in Chrome, in the Elements tab of the Developer Tools, you can right click the node, select Copy > Copy outerHTML).

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean I want the HTML for the table with its newly created values to be displayed in a textbox that I can just copy and paste from.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this? a structure to hold data? a JSON?

```js
var mySt = [
{id: 1, title: "book"},
{id: 2, title: "room"},
{id: 3, title: "park"},
{id: 4, title: "motor"},
{id: 5, title: "bank"}
];

for(var i in mySt){
   var tr= $('<tr><td>' + mySt[i].title + '</td><td><span id="' + mySt[i].title + mySt[i].id + '_output"> sp 1 </span></td><td><span id="' + mySt[i].title + mySt[i].id + '_output"> sp 2 </span></td></tr>');
   $("#myTable").append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<TABLE id="myTable"></TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way I'm not thinking of, but you could copy the entire skeleton of the `<tbody>` to a `string` in `Javascript` and then just concatenate the variables into the string where the values would go, like:

```
var tableString = "<table><tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th class='state-city' colspan='3'>City: <span id='city_output'>"+ cityVariable +"</span></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>2014-15</th>
                                <th>2016-17</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Tuition and Fees</td>
                                <td><span id='tuition1_output'>"+ tuitionVariable1 +"</span></td>
                                <td><span id='tuition2_output'>"+ tuitionVariable2 +"</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Room and Board</td>
                                <td><span id='room1_output'>"+ roomVariable1 +"</span></td>
                                <td><span id='room2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Books</td>
                                <td><span id='books1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='books2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Other Expenses</td>
                                <td><span id='other_expenses1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='other_expenses2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td><span id='total1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='total2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Net Cost (Actual)<br>
                                2014-15</th>
                                <th>Net Cost (Estimated)<br>
                                2016-17</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$0-$30k</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_30k_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_30k_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$30,001 - $48k</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_48k_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_48k_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$48,001 - $75k</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_75k_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_75k_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$75,001 - $110k</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_110k_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_110k_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$110,001+</td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_110k+_1_output'></span></td>
                                <td><span id='income_bracket_110k+_2_output'></span></td>
                            </tr></tbody></table>";
```

I put the first couple variables into the string so you can see. Just make sure all the quotes inside the table are single quotes and the outer ones are double. I noticed you use a mixture of both

Then just:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('netprice-table');
table.innerHTML = tableString;
```

EDIT:
I see you want to generate the `HTML` on the screen to copy and paste it

you could create a `<textarea>` on the page and then display your `tableString` variable inside the `<textarea>`

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('my-textarea');
textarea.value = tableString;
```

This is the updated JS file with everything in one function. Since you were trying to use variables outside the function, but by usinf `var` you are scoping them to be used only in the function.

Also change the rest of the variable names. I changed the first one to `city_output`

```
function generateTable() {
    // City and School
    var school_output = document.getElementById('school_name').value;
    document.getElementById('school_output').innerHTML = school_output;
    var city_output = document.getElementById('city').value;
    document.getElementById('city_output').innerHTML = city_output;
    // Costs 1
    var formInput = document.getElementById('tuition1').value;
    document.getElementById('tuition1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('room1').value;
    document.getElementById('room1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('books1').value;
    document.getElementById('books1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('other_expenses1').value;
    document.getElementById('other_expenses1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('total1').value;
    document.getElementById('total1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('other_expenses1').value;
    document.getElementById('other_expenses1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    // Costs 2
    var formInput = document.getElementById('tuition2').value;
    document.getElementById('tuition2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('room2').value;
    document.getElementById('room2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('books2').value;
    document.getElementById('books2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('other_expenses2').value;
    document.getElementById('other_expenses2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('total2').value;
    document.getElementById('total2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('other_expenses2').value;
    document.getElementById('other_expenses2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    // Income Brackets 1
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_30k_1').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_30k_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_48k_1').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_48k_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_75k_1').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_75k_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_1').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_plus_1').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_plus_1_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    // Income Brackets 2 
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_30k_2').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_30k_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_48k_2').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_48k_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_75k_2').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_75k_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_2').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;
    var formInput = document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_plus_2').value;
    document.getElementById('income_bracket_110k_plus_2_output').innerHTML = formInput;

  var tableString = "<table><tbody><tr><th class='state-city' colspan='3'>City: <span id='city_output'>" + city_output + "</span></th></tr><tr><th>Year</th><th>2014-15</th><th>2016-17</th></tr><tr><td>Tuition and Fees</td><td><span id='tuition1_output'>" + tuition1_output + "</span></td><td><span id='tuition2_output'>" + tuition2_output + "</span></td></tr><tr><td>Room and Board</td><td><span id='room1_output'>" + room1_output + "</span></td><td><span id='room2_output'>"+ room2_output +"</span></td></tr><tr><td>Books</td><td><span id='books1_output'>" + books1_output + "</span></td><td><span id='books2_output'>"+ books2_output +"</span></td></tr><tr><td>Other Expenses</td><td><span id='other_expenses1_output'>"+ other_expenses1_output +"</span></td><td><span id='other_expenses2_output'>" + other_expenses2_output + "</span></td></tr><tr><td>Total</td><td><span id='total1_output'>" + total1_output + "</span></td><td><span id='total2_output'>" + total2_output + "</span></td></tr><tr><th></th><th>Net Cost (Actual)<br>2014-15</th><th>Net Cost (Estimated)<br>2016-17</th></tr><tr><td>$0-$30k</td><td><span id='income_bracket_30k_1_output'>" + income_bracket_30k_1_output + "</span></td><td><span id='income_bracket_30k_2_output'>" + income_bracket_30k_2_output + "</span></td></tr><tr><td>$30,001 - $48k</td><td><span id='income_bracket_48k_1_output'>" + income_bracket_48k_1_output + "</span></td><td><span id='income_bracket_48k_2_output'>" + income_bracket_48k_2_output + "</span></td></tr><tr><td>$48,001 - $75k</td><td><span id='income_bracket_75k_1_output'>" + income_bracket_75k_1_output + "</span></td><td><span id='income_bracket_75k_2_output'>" + income_bracket_75k_2_output + "</span></td></tr><tr><td>$75,001 - $110k</td><td><span id='income_bracket_110k_1_output'>"+ income_bracket_110k_1_output +"</span></td><td><span id='income_bracket_110k_2_output'>" + income_bracket_110k_2_output + "</span></td></tr><tr><td>$110,001+</td><td><span id='income_bracket_110k_plus_1_output'>" + income_bracket_110k_plus_1_output + "</span></td><td><span id='income_bracket_110k_pkus_2_output'>" + income_bracket_110k_plus_2_output + "</span></td></tr></tbody></table>";

var textarea = document.getElementById('my-textarea');
textarea.value = tableString;
}
generateTable();
```

Comment: I set up the skeleton and text area, and there's just one issue, instead of the values generated by the inputs, it just displays "[object HTMLSpanElement]" so e.g. in each span it's "<span id='tuition2_output'>[object HTMLSpanElement]</span>". I've updated the codepen: https://codepen.io/erik-b/pen/wgbqvQ .

Comment: In your `Javascript` file, you are saving everything to the variable `formInput`. You should save each one to a different variable, like the variable name that you used in the table skeleton you setup. For example, you have `city_output` in the table, but you are saving the city field into a variable called `formInput`

Comment: `var city_output = document.getElementById('city').value;`

Comment: Also, the issue is that you are trying to use the variables outside of the function. if you put the table string and the two lines about the textarea inside the function, and change the variable names to correspond to one another, it works. I tested it in your codepen. I will update my answer with a start